# AAC with no global headers is currently not supported

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, codec

As per ffmpeg bitstream filter documentation, if we use  -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc  then the AAC stream from a raw ADTS AAC or an MPEG-TS container to MP4A-LATM.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#aac_005fadtstoasc

But when i try below command the file is not getting converted or adding the bitstream filter

./ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/test_audio.aac -c:a copy  -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc aac_try_with_bsf.aac

I have checked the output format with help fo mediainfo binary.

Could someone help me to figure out the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're the same poster as at ffmpeg-user who posted [this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-July/040487.html).

`.aac` stores a raw bitstream and the demuxer has no facility to extract the stream parameters as extradata. So, you can try streaming like this,

```
./ffmpeg -re -i ~/Downloads/test_audio.aac -acodec copy -vn -rtpflags latm -f rtsp rtsp://shafi:shafi at 192.168.1.135:1935/live/myStream
```